# Unknown and unrecognized POST requests on newly created VPS

Tags: nginx, vps

I created a VPS for a personal project. I've set up an NGINX proxy for incoming traffic. I opened up the server for testing SSL and domain name and put it behind basic auth for the time being.

I just noticed a lot of POST requests coming from http://117.48.205.227 which is trying to access

```
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:27 +0000] "GET /phpdm.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0"
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:28 +0000] "GET /root.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0"
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:28 +0000] "GET /5678.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0"
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:28 +0000] "GET /root11.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0"
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:28 +0000] "GET /xiu.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0"
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:28 +0000] "POST /wuwu11.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:29 +0000] "POST /xw.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:29 +0000] "POST /xw1.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:29 +0000] "POST /9678.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:30 +0000] "POST /wc.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:30 +0000] "POST /xx.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:30 +0000] "POST /xx.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:30 +0000] "POST /s.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:31 +0000] "POST /w.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:31 +0000] "POST /sheep.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
nginx_1    | 117.48.205.227 - - [05/Aug/2019:07:45:31 +0000] "POST /qaq.php HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
```

This is only a small number of all requests. Is someone trying to find unprotected routes or something or is this some weird webcrawler or something?

Anyways, how should I handle this? My webserver is currently closed to the Internet.

Greetings!

Comment: Just the normal background radiation from the dark side of the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are standard hacking attempts from (most likely) compromised VPS farms. You can ignore these attacks, provided that you have hardened your web application and your webserver BEFORE opening it to the internet. The same goes for your SSH server, FTP server and every other entry point to your VPS. If you go to your SSH logs (or any other logs such as FTP) you will see the same type of hacking attempts from the same types of IP addresses. Please look for "VPS hardening" and follow the instructions.